# Need to change the constant to dynamic in this loop

Tags: php, while-loop, logic

I am running Manufacture Schedule (Using PHP Code), but currently its static (means I cannot add holidays OR I cannot change manufacture capacity - Current Manufacturing capacity is static 1700 SQFT per day)

Please see below code

```
$max = 1700;
$dailyLeft = $max;
$current = reset($priorityArraySum);
$output = [];
//$day = date('Y-m-d');
$day = date('Y-m-d');
while (true)    {
  // echo $current."/".$dailyLeft."=".$day.PHP_EOL;
  if ( $current >= $dailyLeft )   {
    //$day=date('Y-m-d', strtotime($day. ' + 1 days'));
    $output[] = ["priority" => key($priorityArraySum), "amount" => $dailyLeft, "day" => $day];
    $day=date('Y-m-d', strtotime($day. ' + 1 days'));
    $current -= $dailyLeft;
    $dailyLeft = $max;
  } else {
    $output[] = ["priority" => key($priorityArraySum), "amount" => $current, "day" => $day];
    $dailyLeft -= $current;
    if ( ($current = next($priorityArraySum)) === false ) {
      break;
    }
  }
}
echo '<pre/>';
print_r($output);
echo '<pre/>';
exit;
```

using above code, I am able to schedule my manufacturing plan, see below image

[current schedule image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aVRlt.png)

Issue with current code is, we have static 1700 per day capacity, we want to have dynamic capacity, like 1700 for day 1, 1900 for day 2, 0 for holidays.

how can we alter this code to make it dynamic?

Currently I am trying below code, but its not working

```
$today=date('Y-m-d');
                $pln_qry=mysql_query("select * from tbl_mfg_schedule where ms_date='".$today."'") or die(mysql_error());
                $pln_data=mysql_fetch_array($pln_qry);
                
                $max = $pln_data['ms_po_sqft'];
                //$max = 1700;
                $dailyLeft = $max;
                $current = reset($priorityArraySum);
                $output = [];
                $day = date('Y-m-d');
                while (true)    {
                    
                    
                    //echo $dailyLeft."</br>";
                
                        if ( $current >= $dailyLeft )   {
                            //$day=date('Y-m-d', strtotime($day. ' + 1 days'));
                            $output[] = ["priority" => key($priorityArraySum),
                                    "amount" => $dailyLeft,
                                    "day" => $day
                            ];
                            $day=date('Y-m-d', strtotime($day. ' + 1 days'));
                            $current -= $dailyLeft;
                            
                            $qryDay=$day;
                            $pln_qry=mysql_query("select * from tbl_mfg_schedule where ms_date='".$qryDay."'") or die(mysql_error());
                            $pln_data=mysql_fetch_array($pln_qry);
                            if($pln_data['ms_po_sqft']==0)
                            {
                                $day=date('Y-m-d', strtotime($day. ' + 1 days'));
                                //continue;
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                    $max = $pln_data['ms_po_sqft'];
                                    $dailyLeft = $max;
                            }
                            
                        }
                        else    {
                            $output[] = ["priority" => key($priorityArraySum),
                                    "amount" => $current,
                                    "day" => $day
                            ];
                            //$dailyLeft -= $current;
                            
                            $qryDay=$day;
                            //$qryDay2=date('Y-m-d', strtotime($day. ' + 1 days'));
                            $pln_qry=mysql_query("select * from tbl_mfg_schedule where ms_date='".$qryDay."'") or die(mysql_error());
                            $pln_data=mysql_fetch_array($pln_qry);
                            if($pln_data['ms_po_sqft']==0)
                            {
                                $day=date('Y-m-d', strtotime($day. ' + 1 days'));
                                //continue;
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                $dailyLeft -= $current;
                            }
                            
                            if ( ($current = next($priorityArraySum)) === false )   {
                                break;
                            }
                        }
                    
                    
                    
                }
```

Comment: Is there some way of knowing what date has what capacity?

Comment: @NigelRen Yes, I have Table in Database, with these columns DATE | CAPACITY

Comment: @NigelRen I have edited my question, pasted code that I am trying now. but its not working properly

Comment: One thing to recommend is to not use the `mysql_` api as it has been deprecated and removed for some time.

Comment: If the second one is not working, what have you tried to check **why** it does not work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is based on the second code you show.  One problem is that you always move the day on and you should only do this in the first part of the `if()` which is where the days capacity is filled up.

To make it easier, I have also retrieved all of the days and capacities up front in a loop and stored them in an array with the date as the key.

```
$today=date('Y-m-d');
$pln_qry=mysql_query("select * 
    from tbl_mfg_schedule 
    where ms_date > '".$today."' 
    order by ms_date") or die(mysql_error());
// Load list of days and production
$plnList = [];
while ( $pln_data=mysql_fetch_array($pln_qry) ) {
    $plnList [ $pln_data['ms_date'] ] = $pln_data['ms_po_sqft'];
}


$current = reset($priorityArraySum);
$output = [];
$day = date('Y-m-d');
// Set max from production plan
$max = $plnList[ $day ];
//$max = 1700;
$dailyLeft = $max;
while (true)    {
    //echo $dailyLeft."</br>";
    
    if ( $current >= $dailyLeft )   {
        //$day=date('Y-m-d', strtotime($day. ' + 1 days'));
        $output[] = ["priority" => key($priorityArraySum),
                "amount" => $dailyLeft,
                "day" => $day
        ];
        $day=date('Y-m-d', strtotime($day. ' + 1 days'));
        $current -= $dailyLeft;
        
        // Move onto the next days capacity, if no specific value assume
        // same as last ( ?? $max)
        $max = $plnList[ $day ] ?? $max;
        $dailyLeft = $max;
        
    }
    else    {
        $output[] = ["priority" => key($priorityArraySum),
                "amount" => $current,
                "day" => $day
        ];
        $dailyLeft -= $current;
        if ( ($current = next($priorityArraySum)) === false )   {
            break;
        }
    }
    
}
echo '<pre/>';
print_r($output);
echo '<pre/>';
```

using some dummy test data (note that the date `2020-08-14` is missing ,so it assumes it will be the same as `2020-08-13`...

```
$priorityArraySum = [2000, 200, 6000, 1200];

$plnList = [ '2020-08-10' => 1700,
        '2020-08-11' => 1700,
        '2020-08-12' => 0,
        '2020-08-13' => 500,
        '2020-08-15' => 1700];
```

it produces...

```
<pre/>Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [priority] => 0
            [amount] => 1700
            [day] => 2020-08-10
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [priority] => 0
            [amount] => 300
            [day] => 2020-08-11
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [priority] => 1
            [amount] => 200
            [day] => 2020-08-11
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [priority] => 2
            [amount] => 1200
            [day] => 2020-08-11
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [priority] => 2
            [amount] => 0
            [day] => 2020-08-12
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [priority] => 2
            [amount] => 500
            [day] => 2020-08-13
        )

    [6] => Array
        (
            [priority] => 2
            [amount] => 500
            [day] => 2020-08-14
        )

    [7] => Array
        (
            [priority] => 2
            [amount] => 1700
            [day] => 2020-08-15
        )

    [8] => Array
        (
            [priority] => 2
            [amount] => 1700
            [day] => 2020-08-16
        )

    [9] => Array
        (
            [priority] => 2
            [amount] => 400
            [day] => 2020-08-17
        )

    [10] => Array
        (
            [priority] => 3
            [amount] => 1200
            [day] => 2020-08-17
        )

)
```

Comment: $max = $plnList[ $day ] ?? $max; this line is giving error, may be due to old PHP version, can you please simplify

Comment: You could change it to `$max = isset($plnList[ $day ]) ? $plnList[ $day ] : $max;`

Comment: Yes changed it to if(isset($plnList[$day]))
        {
         $max = $plnList[$day];
        }
        else
        {
         $max = $max;
        }

Comment: As I couldn't test the SQL part I had missed something, change the line to `where ms_date > '".$today."' ` (it was `=`).  So that it fetches days after the current date and not just that date.

Comment: Yes I too got the issue, it will be >=